# Deep Q-Network: Same Neuron with the Highest Q-Value for all states in the batch

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, q-learning

I'm currently creating a Deep Q-Learning RL agent but noticed the same neuron has the highest Q-value for every sample in the batch. This is noticed from the start of training, and for the duration. As I've applied he_normal initialization I don't believe this should be the case. Each state is a sequence of 20 numbers. Each number in the Sequence is a value between 1.03 and 1.60.

The DQN is as follows:

```
dqn = tf.keras.Sequential()
dqn.add(layers.Dense(20, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal(),input_shape=(1, STATE_SIZE)))
dqn.add(layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal()))
dqn.add(layers.Dense(10, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu, kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal()))
dqn.add(layers.Dense(NUM_ACTIONS, activation="linear", kernel_initializer=tf.keras.initializers.he_normal()))
dqn.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=LEARNING_RATE), loss=tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError())
```

And the output for a batch of 100 (shown below) is an array with the shape (100,3) i.e. there are 3 output neurons. As you will see, the neuron with the highest Q-Value is always the second one.

```
[[2.2714863  2.8333921  0.4768281 ]
 [2.582204   3.5058887  0.65511763]
 [1.3466024  1.603327   0.28956962]
 [2.2741063  3.089935   0.5785622 ]
 [1.9436914  2.223701   0.38582975]
 [2.2485554  3.02261    0.56206   ]
 [1.5067432  1.8800329  0.34724873]
 [2.2780848  2.9197032  0.4713174 ]
 [2.137864   2.7486572  0.5504176 ]
 [2.3158128  2.835751   0.43834403]
 [1.9049102  2.6107268  0.5060439 ]
 [2.0442386  2.5370157  0.41150308]
 [2.440124   3.179787   0.5945551 ]
 [2.1505167  2.9093602  0.53339994]
 [2.58512    3.4193008  0.6160908 ]
 [3.3928902  4.230709   0.8022826 ]
 [1.4068731  1.8791671  0.31053293]
 [1.8420019  2.4199665  0.45984948]
 [2.865584   3.6939511  0.64382017]
 [2.618379   2.8700516  0.6336541 ]
 [1.6936615  2.2972577  0.45703852]
 [2.4216354  2.4927037  0.49120575]
 [2.0442386  2.5370157  0.41150308]
 [2.5803025  3.4499536  0.60959935]
 [1.4931356  1.9112045  0.34653765]
 [2.7176824  3.2883644  0.6340156 ]
 [2.7558522  3.4270773  0.5914624 ]
 [2.598796   3.4613554  0.6834215 ]
 [2.3146057  2.808881   0.48427308]
 [3.867866   5.1233754  0.99717176]
 [2.1642516  2.9553006  0.51944613]
 [3.0724564  3.9202566  0.7221348 ]
 [2.720007   3.517203   0.58011776]
 [2.1472442  2.536253   0.45326298]
 [1.9241515  2.4333878  0.43913066]
 [1.8464688  2.4751573  0.45708334]
 [1.9436914  2.223701   0.38582975]
 [2.599104   3.234971   0.5888583 ]
 [2.6468413  3.290098   0.59045213]
 [2.6808646  3.443099   0.5614922 ]
 [1.5064137  1.8225954  0.29609975]
 [2.4631133  2.732952   0.50768244]
 [2.1503193  2.7819023  0.5076019 ]
 [2.1668513  2.827942   0.5126828 ]
 [2.6106172  3.3932753  0.6045488 ]
 [2.312654   3.0558817  0.57683015]
 [2.1124597  2.850232   0.576217  ]
 [2.7413433  3.2938926  0.6326278 ]
 [1.9757375  2.6023653  0.47410345]
 [2.1661382  2.716541   0.48973867]
 [2.821799   3.6480002  0.6569495 ]
 [2.561199   3.0614908  0.5408259 ]
 [2.1845546  2.7563186  0.43009394]
 [2.2482135  3.2132514  0.638491  ]
 [2.5409188  3.3585439  0.5943327 ]
 [1.4302497  1.7883111  0.28842992]
 [2.2448003  2.8654547  0.55463064]
 [2.4428272  3.2263024  0.56972426]
 [2.0199788  2.7432933  0.5067013 ]
 [1.431719   1.8925757  0.34003294]
 [1.4468833  1.9582862  0.35603273]
 [2.2591689  2.9162276  0.41045833]
 [2.8761647  3.3834503  0.64551383]
 [2.2529485  2.9405181  0.5502021 ]
 [2.401847   3.0659225  0.49365002]
 [2.3216095  2.7469695  0.48033905]
 [2.9452658  3.7953527  0.6531814 ]
 [1.7724941  2.0719523  0.38624394]
 [1.2718548  1.6378831  0.302943  ]
 [2.2714863  2.8333921  0.4768281 ]
 [2.0544264  2.7973657  0.5250687 ]
 [2.669912   3.4828749  0.6020129 ]
 [1.2564961  1.7717506  0.3564956 ]
 [2.6411026  3.378963   0.55519134]
 [2.7026432  3.3677514  0.57472265]
 [2.4050887  3.0448172  0.5102036 ]
 [2.5612283  3.207579   0.5218945 ]
 [2.2146385  3.7526844  1.0732237 ]
 [2.066507   2.4888835  0.35016924]
 [1.8420019  2.4199665  0.45984948]
 [1.3720564  1.9475235  0.40056193]
 [2.3400385  3.0089772  0.5174127 ]
 [2.3432758  3.0362904  0.50847423]
 [2.2482135  3.2132514  0.638491  ]
 [3.0912545  4.140833   0.71635795]
 [2.0860853  2.842556   0.49442607]
 [3.9524555  5.1163425  0.8731067 ]
 [1.4684166  1.6521266  0.34310699]
 [2.8319576  3.7189112  0.63018453]
 [2.5532324  3.0005288  0.5275339 ]
 [3.8995504  5.0905986  0.7478791 ]
 [2.714954   3.400853   0.6375144 ]
 [2.207178   2.88416    0.4962277 ]
 [2.6754792  3.0314918  0.62722415]
 [1.7724941  2.0719523  0.38624394]
 [2.012956   2.4212072  0.38968378]
 [1.2714232  1.5411979  0.25125986]
 [3.2831593  4.331644   0.7733856 ]
 [2.1073704  2.6590524  0.43915245]
 [2.2812588  3.147574   0.72504014]]
```

The loss graph show a decreasing loss, but the reward is still sporadic.

[image: Loss Graph]

[image: Reward Graph]

The code involved in training the agent is outlined below.

```
    def train(self, environment, num_iterations, testing_environment):
        self.iter_num = 0
        # Epsilon - Do we need epsilon if the state space is small?
        self.total_iterations = len(environment.environment_states)*num_iterations
        epsilon_decrement_per_step = 1/self.total_iterations
        # fill replay_buffer
        legal_actions = [0,1,2]
        for i in range(int(trades_replay_buffer.size/3)+1):
            if environment.terminal == True:
                environment.reset()
            states, actions, rewards, state_primes, terminals = environment.step(legal_actions) # fill up buffer with epsilon = 1.0 initially
            for i in range(len(states)):
                trades_replay_buffer.add(state=states[i], action=actions[i], reward=rewards[i], state_prime=state_primes[i], terminal=terminals[i])
        for i in range(num_iterations):
            environment.reset()
            while True:
                if environment.terminal == True:
                    break
                input_state = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(environment.environment_states[environment.current_state_index], newshape=(1, 1, STATE_SIZE)), dtype=tf.float32)
                q_values = self.dqn(input_state, training=False).numpy()
                random_value = random.random()
                action = -1
                if random_value<self.epsilon:
                    action = [random.randint(0, 2)]
                else:
                    action = [np.argmax(q_values)]
                self.epsilon -= epsilon_decrement_per_step
                states, actions, rewards, state_primes, terminals = environment.step(action)
                trades_replay_buffer.add(state=states[0], action=actions[0], reward=rewards[0], state_prime=state_primes[0], terminal=terminals[0])
                
                # Sample from replay buffer
                selected_states, selected_actions, selected_rewards, selected_state_primes, selected_terminals = trades_replay_buffer.sample(BATCH_SIZE) 
                next_states_tensor = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(selected_state_primes, newshape=(BATCH_SIZE, 1, STATE_SIZE)), dtype=tf.float32) #convert next states to tf.tensor of correct shape
                query_results = self.dqn(next_states_tensor, training=False).numpy() 
                best_action_in_next_state_using_main_dqn = query_results.argmax(axis=2) # shape = (100,1)
                target_q_network_q_values = np.reshape(self.target_dqn(next_states_tensor, training=False).numpy(), newshape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_ACTIONS)) # shape = (100,3)
                optimal_q_value_in_next_state_target_dqn = np.zeros(shape=(100,)) # Why are the optimal Q-Values the same across the batch
                for i, v in enumerate(target_q_network_q_values):
                    optimal_q_value_in_next_state_target_dqn[i] = v[best_action_in_next_state_using_main_dqn[i][0]]
                target_q_values = tf.convert_to_tensor(np.add(selected_rewards, np.multiply(np.multiply(GAMMA, optimal_q_value_in_next_state_target_dqn), np.subtract(1, selected_terminals))), dtype=tf.float32)
                with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
                    q_values_current_state_dqn = tf.reshape(self.dqn(tf.convert_to_tensor(np.reshape(selected_states, newshape=(BATCH_SIZE, 1, STATE_SIZE)), dtype=tf.float32), training=False), shape=(BATCH_SIZE, NUM_ACTIONS))
                    one_hot_actions = tf.keras.utils.to_categorical(selected_actions, NUM_ACTIONS, dtype=np.float32) 
                    Q = tf.reduce_sum(tf.multiply(q_values_current_state_dqn, one_hot_actions), axis=1)
                    loss = tf.keras.losses.MeanSquaredError()(target_q_values, Q)
                dqn_architecture_gradients = tape.gradient(loss, self.dqn.trainable_variables) 
                self.dqn.optimizer.apply_gradients(grads_and_vars=zip(dqn_architecture_gradients, self.dqn.trainable_variables))  
                if self.iter_num % 500 == 0:
                    self.target_dqn.set_weights(self.dqn.get_weights())
                if self.iter_num % 100 == 0:
                    with tensorboard_writer.as_default():
                        tf.summary.scalar('REWARD', np.mean(selected_rewards), self.iter_num)
                        tf.summary.scalar('LOSS', loss, self.iter_num)
                        #self.evaluate(testing_environment)
                if self.iter_num % 2500 == 0:
                    print((self.iter_num/self.total_iterations)*100)
                self.iter_num += 1
```